# Want to subset dataframe from beginning to certain value

Tags: r, split, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with induction and observation data, which I want to split into two. The induction goes from the first row to the row with Behavior value "e" and the second has the row to the end.

```
##      Time Behavior
## 1     1.0        D
## 2    46.0        r
## 3   104.1        r
## 4   146.4        r
## 5   164.6        r
## 6   204.5        r
## 7   248.7        r
## 8   261.8        a
## 9   337.2        x
## 10  392.7        a
## 11  609.8        e
## 12  630.6        r
## 13  661.9        u
## 14  664.5        a
## 15  745.6        r
## 16  769.9        r
## 17 1986.1        a
```

I want D -> e in one, and e -> end into a another.

Comment: One possibility is that your dataset may have trailing or leading spaces for the Behavior column. You could get rid off it by `library(stringr); animal1[,2] <- str_trim(animal1[,2])` or you can try `grep("e", animal1[,2])` as in my updated code.

Comment: awesome, both yours and @martin 's code worked after I trimmed it;

Answer (score 0):

```
 indx <- grep("e", dat[,2])
 lst <- setNames( lapply(Map(`:`, c(1,indx), c(indx,nrow(dat))),function(i) dat[i,]),paste0("D",1:2))
 list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)#

  tail(D1,2)
  #     Time Behavior
  #10 392.7        a
  #11 609.8        e
 head(D2,2)
  #    Time Behavior
  #11 609.8        e
 # 12 630.6        r
```

Comment: do I need some way to specify where the dataframes are going/what they are being called? I would like to be able to print them

Comment: indx <- which(animal1[, 2] == "e")
    lapply(Map(`:`, c(1, indx), c(indx, nrow(animal1))), function(i) animal1[i,])
It reprinted the original table, is there a package or something else that I'm missing? Seems like both yours and @martin code should be working at this point...

Comment: the "e" was originally a replacement for another value as per:
    animal1$Behavior = chartr("v","e", animal1$Behavior)

Comment: how do i designate each subset into a seperate variable with this code?

Answer (score 0):

If they are subsequent, you could also do

```
df[1:which(df$Behavior == "e"),] -> first
df[-c(1:which(df$Behavior == "e")),] -> second
```

This puts e in the first data frame only

---

And with e in both:

```
df[1:which(df$Behavior == "e"),] -> first
df[-c(1:which(df$Behavior == "e")-1),] -> second
```

Comment: This is what I put in, animal1 is the dataframe and Behavior is the variable I'm trying to subset by:
    `animal1[1:which(animal1$Behavior == "e"),] -> first`
    `animal1[-c(1:which(animal1$Behavior == "e")-1),] -> second`
I get this: Error: argument of length 0

Comment: seems like your data doesn't have e, then, is that correct?

Comment: It does, I ran the code on the same data frame I posted initially with "e" on row 11